# DataAdapter throws error while filling DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, npgsql, dataadapter

I am trying to fill DataTable using NpgsqlDataAdapter. I have prepared my command as

```
string commandString=@" drop  table if exists tempdata;  
create temp table tempdata as  SELECT X X X X from (_query_);
SELECT x+x, xx, x-y INTO newTempTable FROM tempdata;
```

**And using below function to fill data in datatable**

```
public DataTable Searchpg(string CommandString, NpgsqlParameter[] param)
{
    DataTable ResultTable = new DataTable();
    try
    {

        OpenConnection();

        DbCommandpg.CommandText = CommandString;
        DbCommandpg.Connection = DatabaseConnectionpg;
        DbCommandpg.Parameters.Clear();
        if (param != null)
        {

            DbCommandpg.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        }
        adappg.SelectCommand = DbCommandpg;
        ResultTable.Clear();
        adappg.Fill(ResultTable);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        File.writeException(ex.Message, null);
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        DatabaseConnectionpg.Close();
    }
    return ResultTable;
}
```

**Error Occurs at `adappg.Fill(ResultTable);`**

And error message is **{"42P01: relation \"tempdata\" does not exist"}**
[image]

I am using NpgSql Version **3.0.2.0** , **VS 2013** and **Postgres 9.3**

**BUT** when i run same query in sql editor in pgadmin, it runs finely and return result as per desired.

**UPDATE:** The query works smoothly with Npgsql `2.0.1.0` but not with `3.x`

Comment: from which table that you need to create tmp table ?

Comment: Try like this way `drop  table if exists tempdata;create temp table tempdata as select p_invno,edate,code,product,quantity,unitprice,trancode from tbl`, why did you used to create a `Temp Table` to fill datatable,You can directly use select statement to fill though !

Comment: I am trying to insert data to temp table from result returned by query

Comment: show the exact ( _from result returned by query_) query ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue starting Npgsql 3.x, described here: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/641.

In a nutshell, you cannot create an entity (e.g. table) and use that entity inside the same NpgsqlCommand - simply send your `CREATE TABLE` and your `SELECT` in separate commands.

See the issue above for an explanation, it has to do with some pretty low-level details on how Npgsql communicates with PostgreSQL. Unfortunately it's unlikely we'll fix this very soon.

Comment: I am writing code as `CREATE TEMP TABLE TABLENAME AS SELECT Fields From temp Table` I have more than 4 such commands as single query. Should i create temp table in different query first and then only fill data to that table?